# Formula to use to add up all rows that returned a value of '1' for several cells that meet a specific criterion

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need cell `B21` in the `Reports` sheet to add up all rows that meet this criterion:

> return a value of `1` if columns M, O, T, U, W, X, Z, AA, AB, AC have
>   the answer `No, I do not have psoriasis on this area` in the `Failed`
>   worksheet.

The formula I currently have only applies to row 2.

```
=IF(
   COUNTIF(
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      {Failed!M2,Failed!O2,Failed!T2:U2,Failed!W2:X2,Failed!Z2:AC2}
    ),
   "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area"
   )=10,
   1,
   0
 )
```

How do I sum up all rows?

Comment: As I understand the question, the result should be 1 if all the related cells are "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area" and 0 otherwise. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(N({Failed!M2:M,Failed!O2:O,Failed!T2:U,Failed!W2:X,Failed!Z2:AC}="No, I do not have psoriasis on this area")))
```

After some clarification this formula seems to have worked:

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(MMULT(N({Failed!M2:M,Failed!O2:O,Failed!T2:U,Failed!W2:X,Failed!Z2:AC}="No, I do not have psoriasis on this area"), transpose(split(rept("1+", 10),"+")))), "=10")
```

Comment: The formula in this answer will return the number of cells with "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area" but, as I understand the question, the result should be 1 if all the related cells are "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area" and 0 otherwise.

Comment: ach.. ok.. we interpreted differently. The countif misled me I suppose. The number of rows that have the string is what should be returned..

Comment: Another thing that could cause misleading is the use of 1 and 0 instead of TRUE or FALSE :)

Comment: Rubén, still not sure: if a 1 needs to be returned for a row that has that string in all indicated columns, then the number of rows with a 1 should be 4 ?

Comment: The label at the left of the cell give us a tip: "No psoriasis on this area" :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=IF(
   AND(
     ArrayFormula(
       FILTER(
         {Failed!M2:M,Failed!O2:O,Failed!T2:U,Failed!W2:X,Failed!Z2:AC},
         LEN(Failed!A2:A)
       )
       =
       "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area"
     )
   ),
   1,
   0
 )
```

Comment: Returns an output of 0, which seems incorrect.

Comment: @JPV I double checked and it works fine.

Comment: Not in the sheet the OP shared (see cell B21) ?

Comment: I made a copy of the OP spreadsheet and after that the original file was changed. Not all the related cells in the current version of the OP spreadsheet are equal to "No, I do not have psoriasis on this area", so the result should be 0, and it is :)

Comment: hey JPV and Ruben, looks like one of you gave me the right formula (cell E21). It's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: OMG... I thought I was going crazy.. Glad to hear a solution was found.